# Hack for submitting POST requests in background at regular intervals?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am writing an iOS app for my personal use that POSTs data (such as heart rate and location) to my own Rails API at regular intervals. This process currently works, but only when the app is in the foreground.

I know that Apple has strict regulations about what apps may do in the background, so I want to stress that my question is about coming up with any solution (even a very hacky one) that will only be used on my own personal device. I don't ever plan on submitting this to the App Store.

I found [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started) rather helpful for understanding the typical uses and implementations of background modes, but none seem suited to my needs. I could set up my app to receive location updates while backgrounded, but I want to make POST requests even when I am stationary for long periods of time. The "perform finite-length tasks" case is not an option because I want the loop to run indefinitely.

Very grateful for all your ideas and feedback!

Comment: That tutorial seems like an almost perfect solution to your problem. Have you tried doing POST requests when you get a location update? Maybe your app could store the data and POST it later?

Comment: The way I understand the tutorial, you could probably still do those kind of background requests, but if you try to submit the app it will be rejected.

Comment: This questions seems to describe the problem you have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384306/wake-app-at-regular-intervals-while-using-uibackgroundmodes-location?rq=1

Comment: Maybe you could use the audio background task to do the work you want to do? You did ask for a hack right?

Comment: @simple_code The problem with using location update is that if I'm stationary for some length of time, the function won't be called until I move. The post you linked to seems to verify that limitation

Comment: @simple_code I will try using the audio background task and let you know if that works or not. Thanks for the ideas!